# bottom navigation bar - case not reached

Tags: android, navigation

For some reason, in my bottom navigation bar, my second item doesn't work
But the first one does, I can't figure out why.
when I press the `navigation_building` button , I don't reach the corresponding `case`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:title="•"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_18dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_building"
        android:title="•"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_domain_black_18dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_transfert"
        android:title="•"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_import_export_black_18dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
        android:title="•"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_18dp"/>

</menu>
```

```java
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

                // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.action_logout: {
                        finish();

                    }
                    case R.id.navigation_home: {
                        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.navigation_building: {
                        loadFragment(new BuildingFragment());
                        break;
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `NavigationItemReselectedListener`. This is only triggered when the current selected navigation item is reselected. You are probably looking for `NavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: That was that. Thank you :)